# Display body content as title when Title not present

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-view-controller, view

I am currently working on a web application using Ruby on Rails and wanted to know how I would go about displaying the body contents as the title dynamically if there is no title present? I have validations to only allow titles to be up to 20 characters so I would like to only have it display the first 20 characters of the body as the title should not be present. I'm mostly trying to understand how I would accomplish this would it be by implementing a partial view or utilizing a or statement between how I would be passing in the title?

Comment: There are many solutions to this question - helper methods, presenters, a method on your model etc. without any attempt at a solution the question whe have very little to actually work with and the answers will not be very useful.

Comment: This was less about getting the definitive answer and more about the different ways I could solve this problem. I did end up utilizing a helper method as it this will be used in a couple of places.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A very simple approach would be:

```
<%= instance.title.presence || truncate(instance.body, length: 20) %>
```

Note that you have to replace `instance` with your variable name. When this is used in more than one place then you might want to consider a different approach, like a helper method or a method defined on the model.

Read about [`Object#presence`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Object.html#method-i-presence) and the helper method [`truncate`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/TextHelper.html#method-i-truncate).